# Get application path with JAX-RS service

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS service that I want to know what is the application context path. Before, I was using a `HttpServletRequest` to get the application url, using these methods:

```
public static String getApplicationBaseUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return String.format("%s://%s:%s%s",
                request.getScheme(),
                request.getServerName(),
                request.getServerPort(),
                request.getContextPath());
}
```

I saw the @Context in JAX-RS, but it returns only the paths beginning from JAX resource. What can I do for retrieve the application path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I was using the @Context for `javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo` class, but, I can inject the `HttpServletRequest` too. So, now I can use the getApplicationBaseUrl method that I wrote.